# React-router not displaying component

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs

I'm currently learning react-router, and then trying to implement it in a sample app.

Here is my code:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample APP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>

    <script src="dist/js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

*/src/app.jsx*

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Routes = require('./routes');

ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.getElementById('main'));
```

*/src/routes.jsx*

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;

var HelloWorld = require('./components/hello-world');
var NotFound = require('./components/not-found');
var About = require('./components/about');

module.exports = (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={HelloWorld}>
            <Route path="about" component={About}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

*/src/components/hello-world.jsx*

```
var React = require('react');
var Link = require('react-router').Link;

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <h1>
                Hello World !
            </h1>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </div>
    }
});
```

*/src/components/about.jsx*

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <h1>
            About
        </h1>
    }
});
```

*package.json*

```
{...}
"dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^9.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-react": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-server-livereload": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "history": "^1.13.1",
    "node-notifier": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0",
    "reactify": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^2.4.0"
}
```

*I use `gulp` to `browserify` and `reactify` my sources into `/dist/js/main.js`*

When I click on my `about` link, url changes from `http://localhost:8000/#/?_k=zkmiyh` to `http://localhost:8000/#/about?_k=6nhkao` yet the displayed component is still `hello-world`.

There is no error displayed on my console.

Is there something missing out?

Comment: Your code seems good, have you made sure about renders properly if you put it under "/" directly?

Comment: @Mayas Yes I tried swapping `HelloWorld` and `About` but the behavior is the same : `About` is always displayed, no matter the url

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with react-router, this will most probably fix your problem: `... <Route path="/" component={HelloWorld}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/> ...` even though you might not like it.

Comment: @Mayas You're right it works. Seems odd since nested route is one of the main feature of `react-router`. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. I'll post an issue on their github repo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *ugly* solution is to **get rid of nested routes** like so:

```
module.exports = (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={HelloWorld} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Router>
);
```

---

Yet, I figured it out *the right way to do* via [this doc](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v3.2.6/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md)

We need another component (which I called `Main`) that will contain the right component to display (i.e. `this.props.children`).

I use `IndexRoute` to define the *default* component to display.

Here is the corrected code:

*/src/components/main.jsx (**new**)*

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            // this is where you can add header
            {this.props.children}
            // this is where you can add footer
        </div>
    }
});
```

*/src/routes.jsx (**modified**)*

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var IndexRoute = require('react-router').IndexRoute;

var Main = require('./components/main');
var HelloWorld = require('./components/hello-world');
var About = require('./components/about');

module.exports = (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <IndexRoute component={HelloWorld} />
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: hey ! The doc you linked to doesnt exist. Could you link with to a relevant doc. I am stuck here. :(

Comment: @phoenix I updated [the link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md) in my answer.

Comment: link is broken again.

Comment: @JeromeLanteri I updated the link, again, but all of this is most likely outdated as it was 7 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I have also same prob in my APP I have changed parent and set as same node then it's working may be it may help you

```
module.exports = (
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={HelloWorld} />
    <Route path="about" component={About}/> 
</Router>
```

);

Comment: FYI, I figured out a better solution that the one you use. Check the answer I added for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = (
    <Router>

        <Route path="/"> 
           <HelloWorld/> 
        </Route>

        <Route path="about"> 
           <About/>
        </Route>

    </Router>
);
```

This might help you check this out.

Comment: how is this different from the answer of pistou?

Comment: try it first, you will see it doesn't help to fix anything, but instead add an error because Routes children have to be a Route or React.Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot I had added a BrowserRouter component in my index.js and then had another in my app.js. Once I removed one of them it worked.